# Using where with variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this controller:

```
  public function category($name)
  {
        $users = User::all()->where('category','$name');
        return View('index',['users'=>$users]);  

 }
```

returning to the view:

```
You chose <mark> {{$users[0]->category}}</mark>
```

gives me error:

> undefined offset:0

Comment: Check it out what return `$users` to the view.

Comment: @FrayneKonok it returns all the contents of the table . i require only category column.

Comment: so post the `print_r` the `$users`, if it is a big array then only `$users[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy. The problem is here `'$name'`, change it to simple `$name` (without quotes).

If You want more explanations whats wrong with Your code (not related to this problem), just say it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Controller**

```
public function category($name)
  {
        $user = User::where('category',$name)->select('category')->first();
        return View('index')->with('user', $user);  
 }
```

**VIEW**

```
You chose   <mark> {{ $user }}</mark>
```

Comment: That displayed undefined property category. @Achraf.

Comment: what i did will give you  the first user with the category= $name and it will return only the (category) field

Comment: that code in view is only some part.  I also have to use foreach to retrieve all data. With that first()  it will not work, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Controller :**

```
public function category($name)
  {
        $users=User::where('category',$name)->get();
    return View('index',['users'=>$users]);
 }
```

**View :**

```
@foreach($users as $user) // to access all records
    {{ $user->category }}
@endforeach

{{$users[0]->category}} // to access first record
```

Comment: this is what i have done.  Any difference with the question?

Comment: try using **@foreach** Because i have tried and its working in my PC

Comment: that `@foreach` would work. but it will display category as many times as the records, i guess.

Comment: so you need only first record

Comment: Any record. already i used `where('category','$name');`. so any record have the same value.

Comment: so  @foreach gives you all categories with same as $name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111967/discussion-between-micky-and-yasin-patel).